# FancyArrowPatch not drawing label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't get the FancyArrowPatch to display the text passed to the `label` kwarg. I don't see what I am doing wrong. Any idea?

setup:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

X, Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:.1, -1:1:.1]
Z = X+Y

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ax1.contourf(X, Y, Z)
ax2.contourf(X, Y, -Z)
```

arrow code:

```
ax1tr = ax1.transData # Axis 0 -> Display
ax2tr = ax2.transData # Axis 1 -> Display
figtr = fig.transFigure.inverted() # Display -> Figure
ptB = figtr.transform(ax1tr.transform((0., 0.)))
ptE = figtr.transform(ax2tr.transform((0., 0.)))
arrow = patches.FancyArrowPatch(
    ptB, ptE, transform=fig.transFigure,  # Place arrow in figure coord system
    connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0", arrowstyle='simple',
    mutation_scale = 15., label='some arrow'
)
fig.patches.append(arrow)

fig.show()
```

I would expect *some arrow* to be drawn as the label of the arrow. But it is not.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle it should work after adding `plt.legend()` line in your code. However, there is a workaround solution as follows where you explicitly pass the `arrow` patch and the label text.

```
arrow = patches.FancyArrowPatch(
    ptB, ptE, transform=fig.transFigure,  # Place arrow in figure coord system
    connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0", arrowstyle='simple',
    mutation_scale = 15., label='some arrow'
)
fig.patches.append(arrow)

plt.legend([arrow], fontsize=16)
```

Another alternative is

```
plt.legend(handles=[arrow], fontsize=16)
```

Based on the comments, as I said, the purpose of `label` is not to put the text next to the arrow patch. What you want can be easily achieved using `plt.text`. However, if you don't want to use it, you can make the current code work as desired using the following workaround

```
leg = plt.legend(handles = [arrow], fontsize=16, frameon=False, loc=(0.45, 0.5))

for item in leg.legendHandles:
    item.set_visible(False)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. Unfortunately that's not even what I want (the label next to the arrow).

Comment: @lotolmencre: Then what do you want? Perhaps you should have made your question clearer. Your question reads "I can't get the FancyArrowPatch to display the test passed to the label kwarg" where by "test" I am sure you meant "text"

Comment: I want the label next to the arrow. Like a graphviz label or tikz label.

Comment: I don't think that's what the keyword "label" does. For what you want, you can simply use `plt.text` with a vertically aligned text

Comment: So no way to attach the text to the arrow? That seems clunky, adding it the figure/ the axes/ to `plt`.

Comment: @lotolmencre: The purpose of `label` is not to attach the text to the arrow. What you can do is to hide the legend box using `frameon=False` argument in `plt.legend()` and then remove the legend handle and position the legend box next to the arrow. This way you just will have text (label) in the legend box and this will achieve what you want

Comment: @lotolmencre: Check my edited answer if that serves your purpose

Comment: Ok, thanks. So only hacky, nasty workarounds do the trick. I would have thought such a simple thing would have an easy and elegant solution.

Comment: @lotolmencre: Your expectation was not the purpose of label keyword. But afterall, things needs to be done, even though with such hacks. `label` works as the standard argument like for all other plotting routines (`plt.plot`, `plt.scatter`, etc)

Comment: @lotolmencre: I would suggest to have a look at `plt.annotate`. In that case, the text you provide is placed next to the arrow. You can also have similar arrow styles there.

Comment: Ah! That looks more like what I had in mind, thanks.

Comment: I have skimmed through the annotation docs now, but the part of the API that lets you place arrows with text seems to be restericted to **intra** axes annotation. The part that allows **inter** axes annotation (like `ConnectionPatch` and `FancyArrowPatch`) on the other hand doesn't provide options to place text... I really dislike this API.

Comment: From the docs: "The ConnectionPatch is like an annotation without text. While the annotate function is recommended in most situations, the ConnectionPatch is useful when you want to connect points in different axes."

... yea, but why limit connecting points between different axes to having no text? ...